# Can't access Airflow default_args

Tags: airflow

I'm new to airflow, can someone please help me with this as I'm unable to access 'db_conn' inside my custom operator, this argument defined in default_args.

```
**Dag details:**

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'email': ['example@hotmail.com'],
    'db_conn': 'database_connection'
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='my_custom_operator_dag', description='Another tutorial DAG',
          schedule_interval='0 12 * * *',
          start_date=datetime(2020, 8, 6), 
          catchup=False,
          default_args=default_args)

operator_task_start = MyOperator(                                
                                task_id='my_custom_operator', dag=dag
                                )

**Operator details:**
class MyOperator(BaseOperator):

    #@apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                 *args, 
                 **kwargs):          
        super(MyOperator, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    def execute(self, context):        
        log.info('owner: %s', self.owner)
        log.info('email: %s', self.email)
        log.info('db_conn: %s', self.db_conn) 
        # Error here, AttributeError: 'MyOperator' object has no attribute 'db_conn
```

Comment: I'm using airflow version 1.10.11

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have misunderstood `default_args`. `default_args` is just a shorthand (code-cleanup / refactoring / brevity) to pass common (which have same value for all operators of DAG, like `owner`) args to all your `operator`s, by setting them up as *defaults* and passing to the `DAG` itself. Quoting the [*docstring comment* from `DAG` params](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dag.py#L131)

> ```
> :param default_args: A dictionary of default parameters to be used
>         as constructor keyword parameters when initialising operators.
>         Note that operators have the same hook, and precede those defined
>         here, meaning that if your dict contains `'depends_on_past': True`
>         here and `'depends_on_past': False` in the operator's call
>         `default_args`, the actual value will be `False`.
> :type default_args: dict
> ```

So clearly for `default_args` to work, any `key`s that you are passing there should be an argument of your `Operator` `class`es.

---

Not just that, do note that passing invalid (non-existent) arguments to `Operator` constructor(s) will be [penalized in Airflow 2.0](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L373) (so better not pass any)

> ```
> 'Invalid arguments were passed to {c} (task_id: {t}). '
> 'Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in '
> 'future. ..
> ```

---

Hopefully, by now it must be clear that to make this work, you must add a param `db_conn` in constructor of your `MyOperator` class

```
**Operator details:**
class MyOperator(BaseOperator):

    #@apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                 db_conn: str,
                 *args, 
                 **kwargs):          
        super(MyOperator, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.db_conn: str = db_conn
```

---

And while we are at it, may I offer you a suggestion: for something like a connection, preferably use the [`Connection` feature](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html) offered by Airflow which eases your interaction with external services

- makes them manageable (view / edit via UI)
- secure (they are stored [encrypted in db](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/secure-connections.html))
- support for [load balancing](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=connection#connections) (define multiple connections with same `conn_id`, Airflow will randomly distribute calls to one of those)

> When there is more than one connection with the same conn_id, the
> get_connection() method on BaseHook will choose one connection
> randomly. This can be be used to provide basic load balancing and
> fault tolerance, when used in conjunction with retries.

- nice [integration with built-in `hook`s](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=hook#hooks)

> They also use the airflow.models.connection.Connection model to
> retrieve hostnames and authentication information. Hooks keep
> authentication code and information out of pipelines, centralized in
> the metadata database.